# Converting mysql date from one format to another

Tags: date

I have date stored in a field like this: 31st Dec 2013 but I need to alter it to something like this: 2013-12-31 00:00:00

I have tried lots of variations of DATE_FORMAT and strtotime but got nowhere.  How do I go about this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATE_FORMAT()` function is used to display date/time data in different formats.

Try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%Y %m %d %T:%f')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have it now.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in the way I wanted so I decided to fix it in a totally different way, which was nothing to do with DATE_Format but a search and replace method.  All ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `date_format` inside another `date_format`. The inner one detects the format you are giving, the outer one outputs what you need.