# How to convert dates in "24-Jun-2013" format to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to convert a large table that has dates in the format Day of Month - Month Abbreviation - Year in a row separated by dashes, like `01-Jan-2014`.  The closest question I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586596/converting-mysql-date-from-one-format-to-another) where the asker ended up doing a search and replace method instead.  I could do that too, but I think that surely there is a better way.  My code:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(datecolumn, '%c/%d/%Y') FROM 'Table'
```

Returns null with dates in the above format but is fine with other date formats.  I also tried `DATE_FUNCTION` and other suggestions I saw online.

Comment: Try `str_to_date('01-Jan-2014', '%d-%M-%Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(
      STR_TO_DATE(
        REPLACE(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(datecolumn,'-',-2),
          '-',
          CONCAT(' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(datecolumn, '-', 1), ', ')
        ),
        '%M %d, %Y'
      ),
      '%Y-%m-%d'
    )

FROM `Table`;
```

Explanation:

- We use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(datecolumn,'-',-2)` to get the last two pieces, like `Jan-2014`
- We replace the `-` in `Jan-2014` with the first piece (using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`), i.e., `01`, but also use `CONCAT` to add spaces and `,`, so we get `Jan 01, 2014`
- We use `STR_TO_DATE` and tell it the format is `%M %d, %Y`
- We then put it in `%Y-%m-%d` format with `DATE_FORMAT()`

Examples:

```
07-Jan-2014  ->  2014-01-07
9-May-2001   ->  2001-05-09
13-Dec-1978  ->  1978-12-13
```

[**Here's a fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/badb3/3/0)

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks!